# How does a class referenced to itself work?

Tags: java, oop, class, object

Let's say we have a class like this one:

```
class XCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int orig = 42;
        XCopy x = new XCopy();
        int y = x.go(orig);
        System.out.println(orig + " " + " y);
    }
}
```

I know the `go` method is missing but never mind. Should this work? It appears so, but I just can't picture in my head how that self-reference inside the class works; does it have any side effects? Why does this work? Isn't that some sort of infinite recursive loop?

Anyway, I just can't figure out exactly how this works; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

By calling

```
XCopy x = new XCopy();
```

you are actually calling XCopy's empty constructor, not main method again.

So, the calls look like:

```
JVM calls XCopy.main();
main method creates new instance of XCopy by calling XCopy's empty constructor
XCopy constructor ends
main method ends -> program ends
```

Comment: That's a good way to explain it, and just to be sure. Main() is only called when the program starts, and it can be used without any instances of the class, because it's a static method, correct?

Comment: Yes, main is static, so JVM can call it without instance of your class.

Answer (score 4):

I gather you are looking at this and thinking it is a chicken and the egg type issue, but it's not at all.

If this is your first OO language you are probably confused about Java's terminology.  Java has something called "static methods".  You're main(String[]) method is a static method.  These *static* methods are really just plain old functions.  Object Oriented methods on the other hand are called "instance methods" or just "methods".  People are often sloppy about the terminology.

In Java, a function (i.e. static method) must be defined in the same place as a class and uses that classes' name identify it.  But, it is still just a plain old function.  Sometimes a class just has nothing but a bunch of loosely related functions/static methods.  Like the Math class has a bunch of functions about math.  Sometime a more OO class like string will have some static methods/functions thrown in with the OO methods.

In your program your main function has nothing to do with your class.  But it's still perfectly fine to put it there for a small example.

When Java starts in ALWAYS starts in a main function somewhere (you can tell it what class the main function is in).

So when your program runs the JVM selects your main function as a valid main function.  It runs the function.  Its just a function it doesn't need any objects.  Calling main does not create any objects.

Now, when your are in main(String[]) you happen to create an Object here:

```
XCopy x = new XCopy();
```

Now you have a new object of type XCopy pointed to by the reference (object pointer) x in the local scope of the main function.  If XCopy had a constructor it would have been called.

So if you want to picture it in your head let me write it in a fictitious language for you that has a clear more visual syntax!

here it is:

```
Namespace XCopy 
{
  function void main(String[]) 
  { 
    int orig = 42;
    XCopy x = new XCopy();
    int y = x.go(orig);
    System.out.println(orig + " " + " y);
  }
}

Class XCopy
{
   method int go(int i) 
   {
      ....
      return whatever;
   }
}
```

In this same program in this other languages' syntax you can see that you have one function, one class with one method, and you have one instance of that class.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Why would it recurse? `main()` isn't called anywhere within itself, so it wouldn't recurse. A class is in scope of its own members, so you can create instances of it.

Take for instance a `makeCopy()` method; it would need to create an instance of another object of its own type.

Don't think of methods as being "inside" a class/object and the action of calling a method from within itself as anything awkward; a method is just a function with an implicit `this` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The main method is static, meaning that its code can be accessed independently of the fact that there is an instance of Xcopy. Hence, there is no conflict or recursive loop. It has its own memory space which is different than the memory space allocated for each class instance.

Answer (score 1):

main() is static, therefore you can consider it part of the class, but not of an instance. It gets called by OS+JVM and creates an instance of a class. That class happens to be the class where main() is defined, but that really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a different class:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private Person favorite;
  public Person(String name) { setName(name); }
  public void setFavorite(Person favorite) {this.favorite = favorite;}
  public Person getFavorite() { return favorite; }
  public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Person a = new Person("Alex");
    Person b = new Person("Becky");
    Person c = new Person("Chris");
    Person d = new Person("David");
    a.setFavorite(b);
    b.setFavorite(c);
    c.setFavorite(c);
  }
}
```

So, Alex's favorite person is Becky. Becky's favorite person is Chris. But Chris is a narcissist; his favorite person is himself. David doesn't have a favorite person. Sadly, nobody thinks David is their favorite person.

When you apply the concept of self-references to something with real-world semantics, doesn't it make sense that such a structure is possible? Note, setting a self-reference doesn't create a copy. There is still only one Chris in this program.

As long as you don't make the move of saying, "I'm going to ask each person who their favorite person is. Then I'm going to ask that person who their favorite person is. I'm not going to stop until I find David. Because then, you do have a chance at looping forever.